# SMTP issue magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, exception, smtp

I am using Aschroder SMTP Pro extension, suddenly the extension stopped working and giving below exception:
**On Testsite for gmail**

```
2020-07-20T05:37:03+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor b8sm9558176pjd.5 - gsmtp
' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/Login.php(95): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(235)
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth()
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Queue.php(99): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#6 [internal function]: Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(326): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/cron1.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#13 {main}
```

**On production site for Outlook:**

```
2020-07-23T07:51:20+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SG2PR06CA0235.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com]
' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/Login.php(95): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(235)
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth()
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php(132): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template->send('sales@c...', NULL, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Magecomp/Recaptcha/controllers/IndexController.php(149): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('contacts_email_...', 'custom2', 'sales@c...', NULL, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magecomp_Recaptcha_IndexController->saveAction()
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /var/www/html/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

This when I Run for test email to check that SMTP details working or not.

Comment: Did you tried re-authorizing ?

Comment: I checked all credentials and put there and save but its not working

Comment: there is security issue that's why it's blocking your email

Answer (score 0):

i have a problem with this extension too.
Since 24.07. no order mails will sent out.
All other mails will correctly sent and the selftest of SMTP Pro is complete and correcly but the order mails will not sent.

I'm confuise. I tested the cronjobs too, everything is working fine and i haven change anything.

```
2020-07-29T13:58:35+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.7.1 Spam message rejected
' in /html/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(324): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(250, 600)
#1 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(215): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->data('To: =\?utf-8\?B\?T...')
#2 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#3 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#4 /html/magento/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php(132): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#5 /html/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#6 /html/magento/app/code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachments/Model/Core/Email/Template/Mailer.php(42): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('6', 'general', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#7 /html/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1355): Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Core_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#8 /html/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1370): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail(true)
#9 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#10 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->emailAction()
#11 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
#12 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /html/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

One full day of working later....
I find out that my Serverhost has set the maximum of attachment to under 100kb. So i deleted some attachment and now everything is working fine. I hope this can help someone who has the same issue.